# Pauli Operators

Tags: particle-physics

Is the superposition of two spin states $(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle)$ an eigenstate of any of the Pauli matrices? Can an eigenstate of an operator be a superposition of two or more eigenstates of the operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take Pauli matrix $\sigma_x$ you can easily see:

$$
\sigma_x \cdot (|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} =
(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle)
$$
So we can conclude that the vector $(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle)$ is an eigenstate of Pauli matrix $\sigma_x$.

As for your other question, if we have eigenvalue that is degenerate then the superposition of corresponding eigenvectors is also an eigenvector. In general, the superposition of two eigenvectors does not give an eigenvector.

However in your particular case we have something different. You are taking the superposition of two eigenvectors ($|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$) of matrix $\sigma_x$ and you are asking if such state is eigenvector of a totally different matrix (other Pauli matrix). In that case we cannot say anything general (for some random matrices), but in this particular example it turns out that the vector you were interested in is indeed eigenvector of $\sigma_x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then what's wrong with saying that the electron in that superposition state has a definite spin orientation? What is the answer to the question "What is the spin orientation of the electron along the x axis?" Do we have a definite answer to this question?

Comment: more accurately a superposition of two eigenvectors of an operator, having different eigenvalues, is not an eigenvector of this original operator.  The eigenvalues of the Pauli matrices are distinct so a linear combo of eigenstates of $\sigma_k$ will not be an eigenstate of $\sigma_k$.

Comment: @Anti-Tachyon Your state does have definite spin along $\hat x$, but not along $\hat z$ or $\hat y$ so it depends very much on how the question is phrased.  The notion of superposition also implies a choice of basis.

Answer (score 1):

To your second question: yes.  If the operator has repeated eigenvalues, and distinct eigenvectors corresponding to these repeated eigenvalues, then a linear combo of these eigenvectors will also be an eigenvector with this common eigenvalue.

The canonical example is found in the eigenstates of the hydrogen atom.  There are 4 states with energy $E_2=-13.6/4$eV and any linear combination of those is also an eigenstate with energy $E_2$.

Another example would be the harmonic oscillator states $\vert 0\rangle$ and $\vert 2\rangle$.  Both are eigenvectors of the parity operator with eigenvalue $+1$, and their combination $\alpha \vert 0\rangle +\beta \vert 2\rangle$ is also an eigenvector of parity with eigenvalue $+1$.

To your first question: if you work in a finite dimensional space then any vector is an eigenstate of *some* operator.  The simplest example would be in 2-dimensional space.  Start with 
\begin{align}
\vert\psi\rangle =\left(\begin{array}{c} \alpha \\ \beta \end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad 
\vert 1\rangle =\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 0\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
where $\vert\alpha\vert^2+\vert\beta\vert^2=1$.  Construct the *unitary* matrix 
\begin{align}
U= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & -\beta^*\\
\beta&\alpha^*\end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad 
U^{\dagger}=\left(U^\top\right)^*=U^{-1}
\end{align}
so that $\vert \psi\rangle=U\vert 1\rangle$. Then $\vert\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the operator
\begin{align}
D_U=U\cdot D \cdot U^\dagger\, ,\qquad D=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 &\lambda_2\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ since
\begin{align}
D_U\vert\psi\rangle&= U\cdot D\cdot U^{\dagger} U \vert 1\rangle\, ,\\
&=U D\vert 1\rangle \, ,\\
&=\lambda_1 U\vert 1\rangle = \lambda_1 \vert\psi\rangle\, .
\end{align}
Whether or not the operator $D_U$ has any meaning in your theory is a different matter.

Finally, note that, in larger dimensions, the matrix $U$ is not completely determined by the vector $\vert\psi\rangle$: $U$ can be multiplied from the right by any matrix $T$ so that $T\vert 1\rangle=e^{i\varphi}\vert 1\rangle$ and produce the same $\vert\psi\rangle$.